# Grid in a form panel in extjs

Tags: extjs4

i have a grid within a form as in the attached image. when the customer name is changed, then the grid store is loaded with records corresponding to the customer. i want to post the grid values together with the form values! How can this be done?

The image is found [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?210737-Grid-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have `autoSync: true` for your grid store. To save all dirty records you would need to call `store.sync()`

Comment: what i need is for the selected grid records to be saved with the payment amounts

Comment: That's fine. After you load your customer record you will filter other store to show only records belong to this customer. Then you change them and then do sync. Everything will be saved.

Comment: i get your concept never thought it that way